# Как получить значение data, которое передает php на js

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Возникла такая проблема, мне нужно следующее:
1. PHP передает значение на js в `data`
2. JS проверяет, какое значение ему было передано и выдолняет соответствующий код.
Проблема в следующем:
Я не могу просто написать `if(data == "true"){`, это не работает, как получить значение из data?
Код js:

```
function onLogin(data)
            {
                if(data == "true"){
                    alert("true");
                }
                if(data == "false"){
                    alert("false");
                }
            }
```

Код php (да, пользователь должен ввести в качестве логина true или false, но это я потом исправлю, сейчас нужно именно научиться получать значение из data):

```
<?php
$login = $_POST['login'];
echo("$login");
?>
```

Отправка данных на сервер PHP:

```
$.post(
                            "check.php",
                            {
                            login: login
                            },
                            onLogin
                            );
```

Comment: Добрый день. Покажите код, которым Вы отправляете на сервер данные, код, который обрабатывает на сервере данные.

Comment: PHP код добавил. PHP передает ответ через `echo` после того, как js отправил значение переменной `login`

Comment: Как Вы отправляете данные на сервер?

Comment: Извиняюсь, вот добавил

Comment: Добавил в ответ вариант запроса через $.post. Хотя у вас должно работать тоже. Возможно где то другая проблема.

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример с вашим запросом. Функции выполняются асинхронно поэтому код выглядит как то так.

```
//кроссбраузерное создание объекта для работы с запросом
function getXmlHttp(){
  var xmlhttp;
  try {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  } catch (e) {
    try {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (E) {
      xmlhttp = false;
    }
  }
  if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  return xmlhttp;
}

//основной код в виде отдельной функции
function main() {
    // (1) создать объект для запроса к серверу
    var req = getXmlHttp()  


//функция которая выполнится после получения ответа сервера
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {  

        if (req.readyState == 4) { 
      // тут ваши действия если сервер не ответил
      console.log("Сервер не отвечает");
    }
    else {
        if(req.status == 200) { 
        // если статус 200 (ОК) - проверяем данные
                data=req.responseText;
        //и вот тут ваши действия
        if(data == "true"){
                    alert("true");
                }
                if(data == "false"){
                    alert("false");
                }
            }
            // тут можно добавить else с обработкой других ошибок запроса
        }

    }

       // тут собственно выполняем запрос. у вас может быть другой адрес
    req.open('GET', '/ajax/data.php', true);  
    req.send(null);

        // Дальше просто ждем пока выполнится запрос
    console.log("Ожидаю ответа сервера..."); 
}
```

Если вы работаете через jq, то вам нужно написать как то так.

```
 $.post(
        "check.php",
        {
        login: login
        },
        .done(function(data) {onLogin(data);})
        );
```

Хотя это эквивалентно вашему варианту.